# Password Checker UpperCase

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is my small program I am working

> Build a password checker. It will take string input. Condition:
>   password string must contain at least one upper case, one lower case,
>   one number and length must be minimum 8 characters. Otherwise it will
>   say ‘invalid password’.

I am trying with the below codes

```
password = str(raw_input("Enter the password: "))

if password.isalnum() == False:
    print "Password should contain atleast one special character or number"
if password.isalnum() == False:
    print "Password should contain atleast one numeric number"
elif len(password)<8:
    print 'Too short'
elif password.isupper() == False:
    print 'Password should contain atleast one uppercase character'
elif password.islower() == False:
    print 'Password should contain atleast one lowercase character'
else:
    print "Password is OK"
```

But it is inconsistent, it is asking for uppercase even it is there,

```
Enter the password: niswdgER41
Password should contain atleast one uppercase character
```

Comment: I'd recommend regex instead.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I absolutely wouldn't recommend regex to someone who clearly doesn't bother reading the docs!

Comment: isupper returns TRUE if ALL characters in the string is upper-case. Which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of mistakes, but the most important one is that all the methods you use check if the entire string upholds the condition, rather than once of its chars.

Change it to:

```
def validate_password(pwd):
    conds = [
        lambda s: any(x.isupper() for x in s),
        lambda s: any(x.islower() for x in s),
        lambda s: any(x.isdigit() for x in s),
        lambda s: len(s) >= 8
    ]

    return all(cond(pwd) for cond in conds)
```

But, if you really want the user to know what is missing, you could use the following implementation:

```
def validate_password(pwd):
    conds = {
        "uppercase": lambda s: any(x.isupper() for x in s),
        "lowercase": lambda s: any(x.islower() for x in s),
        "number": lambda s: any(x.isdigit() for x in s),
        "length": lambda s: len(s) >= 8
    }

    valid = True
    for name, cond in conds.iteritems():
        if not cond(pwd):
            print "Password lacking " + name
            valid = False

    if valid:
        print "Password OK"
    else
        print "Password Invalid"
    return valid
```

Comment: You can even throw this into a function. `def valid_password(password):`

Comment: However you are removing the Traceback for a user to identify why the password is bad. :(

Comment: Added a solution that includes tracing :)

Comment: Hi, If i enter only lowercase in password, it returns lacking uppercase, how to return both number and uppercase missing.

Comment: Updated to include all criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can check all characters in the string with a list comprehension:

```
contains_upper_case_character = any([letter.isupper() for letter in password])

# contains_upper_case_character is True if password contains an uppercase letter.
```

If you want to extend this to more that one upper case letter:

```
password = 'StrinG12'
upper_case_letters = [letter.isupper() for letter in password].count(True)

print(upper_case_letters)
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkpassword ():
    password = input ("please enter password")




def menu ():
    print ("1. Check Password")
    print ("2. Generate Password")
    print ("3. Quit")
    optionchoice = input (" please chose a menu,1,2,3")
    if optionchoice == "1":
        checkpassword()
    elif optionchoice == "2":
        pass
    elif optionchoice == "3":
        pass
    else :
        print ("invalid answer!")
        menu()


menu()
```